# Speeding up Test-Path and GCI on large data set

Tags: powershell

I have a large list of Customer IDs (40,000). Files for each Customer have been saved in many different locations. I first run a Test-Path to see if the directory exists, if it does then I run Get-ChildItem and filter down the results to find the file I need (Any file matching string 'Contract'). I am hoping to educate myself on how to speed this up, I have attempted to introduce another variable 'Trigger' to try and prevent some of the excess code from running if the matching file is found. It is taking a very long time to loop this through 40,000 times so if there is a better way any help greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Here is the code I'm currently using

```
    ForEach ($Customer in $CustomerList)
    {
    $Trigger = 0
    $Result1 = Test-Path "$Location1\$Customer"
    $Result2 = Test-Path "$Location2\$Customer"
    $Result3 = Test-Path "$Location3\$Customer"
    
    IF ($Result1 -eq $True)
    {
    $1Files = GCI "$Location1\$Customer" -Recurse
    
    ForEach ($File IN $1Files)
    {
    IF ($Trigger -eq 0)
    {
    $FileName = $File.Name
    $FileLocation = $File.FullName
    
    IF ($FileName -match 'Contract')
    {
    $Report += "$FileName $FileLocation"
    $Trigger = 1
    }
    }
    }
    }
    
    ELSEIF ($Result2 -eq True)
    {
    Same as result 1 codeblock but using $Location2
    }
    
    ELSEIF ($Result3 -eq True)
    {
    Same as result 1 codeblock but using $Location3
    }
    
    }
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem <path> -Recurse -File -Filter *Contact*`

Comment: Please properly indent your code sample.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, please feel free to add as answer as this dramatically sped up the code (reduced from hours to approx 30 minutes by filtering via GCI instead). Also sorry Zett, I dont use indenting myself as I can just read code chronologically with no issue so I've never actually learnt how to do that properly.